# Conditional probability question: bags with balls.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are three bags with balls.

For each bag probability of picking up a red ball is `0.1`. But if person picks a red ball on previous bag, then on subsequent bags probability of picking up a red ball is `0`. For example, if person picks the ball on first step, then it can't pick the red ball on further steps.

Find the probability that it will not pick up the red ball.

Attempt on solution.

Let probability of picking a red ball from `i-th` bag is $P(A_i)$ and probability of not picking is $P(B_i)$.

As can be seen at most one red ball can be picked.
So, $P(A_1)=0.1$, $P(A_2)=0.9\cdot0.1$, $P(A_3)=0.9\cdot0.9\cdot0.1$.

Thus, probability of not picking is $1-P(A_1)-P(A_2)-P(A_3)=1-(0.1+0.9\cdot0.1+0.9\cdot0.9\cdot0.1)=0.729$, which is $0.9^3$ and looks like it is independent non-picking of red ball.

From another side:
$P(B_1)=0.9$
$P(B_2)=P(B_2|B_1)\cdot P(B_1)+P(B_2|A_1)\cdot P(A_1)=0.9\cdot0.9+1\cdot0.1=0.91$
$P(B_3)=P(B_3|B_2)\cdot P(B_2)+P(B_3|A_2)\cdot P(A_2)=0.9\cdot0.91+1\cdot0.09=0.909$

So, probability of not picking the red ball is $P(B_1)P(B_2)P(B_3)=0.9\cdot0.91\cdot0.909=0.744471$

Which solution is wrong? Or both?

Comment: Is he picking $3$ times and $1$ ball out of each bag?

Comment: Yes. You're correct.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you find which solution is wrong?

Comment: But from first solution answer is $0.729=0.9^3$,  Probabilities of not picking the ball are not independent, but answer suggest another or am I wrong?

Comment: No I was not wrong. There is no independence. Indeed $0.729=0.9^3$ but that does suggest independence here, since we don't have $P(B_i)=0.9$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: I got your idea, but independence of what does it suggest?

Comment: You might call it "independence of conditional events". See my answer.

Comment: One more question. I found that $P(A_3)=0.9\cdot0.9\cdot0.1=0.081$, $P(B_3)=0.909$, but $P(A_3)+P(B_3) \neq 1$

Comment: If $B_2$ occurs then possibly a red ball has been drawn at the first draw. So $P(B_3|B_2)\neq0.9$ as you suggest. This spoils your calculation of $P(B_3)$.

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have: $$P(B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3)=P(B_1)P(B_2\mid B_1)P(B_3\mid B_1\cap B_2)=0.9\times0.9\times0.9$$

Comment: Looks like your answer is wrong, since $P(A_3)\neq0.9\cdot0.9\cdot0.1$

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct.